# Pandas associate or filter a date column between a range and groupby another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, sentiment-analysis

I am new to pandas and I am trying to carry out some EDA on my twitter dataset. [Dataset column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2wWA.png)

Link to Dataset : https://www.kaggle.com/kaushiksuresh147/the-social-dilemma-tweets

Dataframe Sample : [Sample dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hemU4.png)

I want to filter new users created (from the user_created column) between "2020-09-08 and 2020-09-22" and then group the results with the sentiment column. I also want to count the total number of tweets created from this new users within that period and compare it with the overall number of tweets from other users which are not in the selected range(2020-09-08 and 2020-09-22).

I have tried an approach and my code keeps giving me the error message : KeyError: 'user_created'[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t7Ga.png)

I also tried this code which also gives me error message:KeyError: 'user_created'[2nd code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGpDZ.png)

```
df['user_created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['user_created'])
start = '2020-09-08'
end = '2020-09-20'
df[(df['user_created'] >= start) & (df['user_created'] <= end)]
df[(df['user_created'] >= '2020-09-08') & (df['user_created'] <= '2020-09-22')]
grouped_df = df.groupby(['user_name', 'Sentiment','user_created']).size().reset_index(name="Count")
print(grouped_df.to_string(header=False))
```

I have tried the df.get(user_created) to retrieve this column but it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `start` and `end` should be in datetime format (`datetime.datetime`, `np.datetime64`, or `pd.Timestamp`), not in string format.

```
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime.strptime('2020-09-08', '%Y-%m-%d')
end = datetime.strptime('2020-09-20', '%Y-%m-%d')
df[(df['user_created'] >= start) & (df['user_created'] <= end)]
```

Comment: Thank you. As you suggested I changed it to datetime format using datetime.datetime and I still have the KeyError: 'user_created' error.